Ubuntu, upon opening laptop after having it closed, either does not wake up, or applications will stop responding, and computer will restart by itself
I just got an Acer Aspire 3.15 laptop, and took windows 11 off, and put Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on.
I have noticed that if I close or suspend the laptop, if I come back to it after a while, the screen will remain blank, and I have to turn it off (via power button) and turn it back on.
If I come back in a short period, it will work fine for a couple of minutes, then no applications will work and the laptop will restart by itself.
It's very annoying and I don't know how to fix it.

A note, maybe not so useful, but anyway: Ubuntu 24.04 will start in less than a minute if all is well, so: Avoid using the suspend option - it is apparently not well supported(?) by all software.

If I remember correctly, I think it automatically uses suspend when you close the laptop. Is there a way to change that?

I assume this is software -controlled, so maybe... I do not know details though.

Edit your question and add system details. Suspension and especially hibernation with linux does not always work well because of proprietary hardware. Look into the settings to disable Automatic Suspend.

Alternative to Suspend / Sleep mode:
Maybe not so useful if you're "in" to Suspend mode, but anyway:
Ubuntu 24.04 will start in less than a minute if all is well, so: Avoid using the suspend option - it is apparently not well supported(?) by all software.
A helper here may be a shortcut key as in:
Settings > Keyboard > View and Customize shortcuts > Custom shortcuts > +
Name: Shutdown, Single Dialog  
Command: gnome-session-quit --power-off  
Shortcut: Shift+F12  

Hitting that key-combo will shutdown the PC/Laptop very quickly,
at least assuming you DON'T have unsaved work in some software.
(it MAY also cause unsaved work to be lost, depending on software and situation; be warned!)
Tip:
If you wish to re-open all tabs that were open in Firefox:
Alt+s + Restore Previous Session
